# Secure entities using Voters

Tags: php, security, symfony

I have three entities: **User**, **Store** and **Category**.
**User** has a bidirectional relation with **Store** and **store** has a bidirectional relation with **Category** also.
Each user can create many stores and he can create many categories for each one.
I have managed to secure the store using Voters and user can access only to his stores.

This is the route of store

```
dashboard_store_view:
path:     /{id}/view
defaults: { _controller: ProjectStoreBundle:StoreDashboard:view }
```

The url is like this

```
http://localhost/project/web/app_dev.php/dashboard/store/1/view
```

This is the controller **StoreDashboardController.php**

```
<?php
//..................
    public function viewAction(Store $store)
{
    // keep in mind, this will call all registered security voters
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('view', $store)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Unauthorised access!');
    }       
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $store = $em->getRepository('ProjectStoreBundle:Store')->findOneById($store);

    return $this->render('ProjectDashboardBundle:Store:view.html.twig',
    array(
        'store' => $store 
    ));
}
```

And this is the **StoreVoter**

```
    <?php

namespace Project\StoreBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class StoreVoter implements VoterInterface
{
const VIEW = 'view';
const EDIT = 'edit';
const DELETE = 'delete';

public function supportsAttribute($attribute)
{
    return in_array($attribute, array(
        self::VIEW,
        self::EDIT,
        self::DELETE,
    ));
}

public function supportsClass($class)
{
    $supportedClass = 'Project\StoreBundle\Entity\Store';

    return $supportedClass === $class || is_subclass_of($class, $supportedClass);
}

/**
 * @var \Project\StoreBundle\Entity\Store $store
 */
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $store, array $attributes)
{
    // check if class of this object is supported by this voter
    if (!$this->supportsClass(get_class($store))) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    // check if the voter is used correct, only allow one attribute
    // this isn't a requirement, it's just one easy way for you to
    // design your voter
    if(1 !== count($attributes)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            'Only one attribute is allowed for VIEW or EDIT'
        );
    }

    // set the attribute to check against
    $attribute = $attributes[0];

    // get current logged in user
    $user = $token->getUser();

    // check if the given attribute is covered by this voter
    if (!$this->supportsAttribute($attribute)) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    // make sure there is a user object (i.e. that the user is logged in)
    if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
    }

    switch($attribute) {
        case 'view':
            // we assume that our data object has a method getUser() to
            // get the current owner user entity for this data object
            if ($user->getId() === $store->getUser()->getId()) {
                return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
            break;
        case 'edit':
            // we assume that our data object has a method getUser() to
            // get the current owner user entity for this data object
            if ($user->getId() === $store->getUser()->getId()) {
                return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
            break;
        case 'delete':
            // we assume that our data object has a method getUser() to
            // get the current owner user entity for this data object
            if ($user->getId() === $store->getUser()->getId()) {
                return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
            break;

    }
}
}
```

I tried to do the same thing with categories but I failed to secure each category to his own store and so evry user can edit any category

This is the route

```
dashboard_category_edit:
pattern:  /{store_id}/edit/{id}
defaults: { _controller: ProjectStoreBundle:CategoryDashboard:edit }
```

The url is like this

```
http://localhost/project/web/app_dev.php/dashboard/categories/store/1/edit/3
```

**CategoryDashboardController.php**

```
    public function editAction(Category $category, Store $store)
{       
    // keep in mind, this will call all registered security voters
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('edit', $store)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Unauthorised access!');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryEditType(), $category);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();   
            $em->persist($category);
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Category bien modifié');

            return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('dashboard_category_index', array('store_id' => $store->getId())));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('ProjectDashboardBundle:Category:edit.html.twig',
    array(
        'form' => $form->createView() ,
        'store' => $store
        ));
}
```

and this is the **CategoryVoter**

```
<?php

namespace Project\StoreBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class CategoryVoter implements VoterInterface
{
const VIEW = 'view';
const EDIT = 'edit';
const DELETE = 'delete';

public function supportsAttribute($attribute)
{
    return in_array($attribute, array(
        self::VIEW,
        self::EDIT,
        self::DELETE,
    ));
}

public function supportsClass($class)
{
    $supportedClass = 'Project\StoreBundle\Entity\Category';

    return $supportedClass === $class || is_subclass_of($class, $supportedClass);
}

/**
 * @var \Project\StoreBundle\Entity\Category $category
 */
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $category, array $attributes)
{
    // check if class of this object is supported by this voter
    if (!$this->supportsClass(get_class($category))) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    // check if the voter is used correct, only allow one attribute
    // this isn't a requirement, it's just one easy way for you to
    // design your voter
    if(1 !== count($attributes)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            'Only one attribute is allowed for VIEW or EDIT'
        );
    }

    // set the attribute to check against
    $attribute = $attributes[0];

    // get current logged in user
    $user = $token->getUser();

    // check if the given attribute is covered by this voter
    if (!$this->supportsAttribute($attribute)) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    // make sure there is a user object (i.e. that the user is logged in)
    if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
    }

    switch($attribute) {
        case 'view':
            // we assume that our data object has a method getUser() to
            // get the current owner user entity for this data object
            if ($user->getId() === $category->getStore()->getUser()->getId()) {
                return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
            break;
        case 'edit':
            // we assume that our data object has a method getUser() to
            // get the current owner user entity for this data object
            if ($user->getId() === $category->getStore()->getUser()->getId()) {
                return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
            break;
        case 'delete':
            // we assume that our data object has a method getUser() to
            // get the current owner user entity for this data object
            if ($user->getId() === $category->getStore()->getUser()->getId()) {
                return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
            break;

    }
}
}
```

The problem is that categories is not realted to user but it is related to store, so how can I secure it ?

---

I find this solution doing verification if $category->getStore <> $store so throw **AccessDeniedException** without using Voters and it work fine now.

```
    if ($category->getStore() <> $store) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Unauthorised access!');
    }
```

So the controller will be like this

```
    /**
* @ParamConverter("store", options={"mapping": {"store_id":"id"}})
*/
public function editAction(Category $category, Store $store)
{       

    if ($category->getStore() <> $store) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Unauthorised access!');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryEditType(), $category);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();   
            $em->persist($category);
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Category bien modifié');

            return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('dashboard_category_index', array('store_id' => $store->getId())));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('ProjectDashboardBundle:Category:edit.html.twig',
    array(
        'form' => $form->createView() ,
        'store' => $store
        ));
}
```

Is it a good solution ?

Comment: Each `Category` can have only one `Store`?

Comment: Yes , Each Category can have only one Store and a Store can have many categories

Comment: What's happen in your _StoreVoter_ if the user doesn't match with the _Store_'s owner ? You don't return an ACCESS_DENID ?

Comment: In the url there are two parameters , id_store and id_category, 
If the user doesn't match with the Store's owner it return an ACCESS_DENID
but the problem is if Category dosn't match with the Store's ID it doesn't return an ACCESS_DENID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution that getting the ID of store in table category then doing two verifications,
if id_store in table category doesn't match Store's owner and if id_store in table category doesn't match current store

```
/**
* @ParamConverter("store", options={"mapping": {"store_id":"id"}})
*/
public function editAction(Category $category, Store $store)
{       

    // get id_store in table category
    $idStore = $category->getStore(); 

    // if id_store in table category doesn't match user 
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('edit', $idStore)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Unauthorised access!');
    }       

    // if id_store in table category doesn't match current store
    if (false === ($idStore === $store)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Unauthorised access!');
    }       

    $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryEditType(), $category);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();   
            $em->persist($category);
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Category bien modifié');

            return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('dashboard_category_index', array('store_id' => $store->getId())));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('ProjectDashboardBundle:Category:edit.html.twig',
    array(
        'form' => $form->createView() ,
        'store' => $store
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If each `Category` has only one `Store` ther is no point in using `store_id` in route when you want to edit `Category`. Just use `category_id` and get `$store` from `$category` by calling `$store = $category->getStore();`. Change `editAction`:

```
/**
* @ParamConverter("category", options={"mapping": {"category_id":"id"}})
*/
public function editAction(Category $category)
{       
    // keep in mind, this will call all registered security voters
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('edit', $category)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Unauthorised access!');
    }
    $store = $category->getStore();
    (...)
```

Comment: I don't know if check the granted access on a category is the best way to do. As the user has a relationship with Store, the check must be on Store object ?

Comment: So just do the check on `$store` after you get it by `$store = $category->getStore();`